# How to create a AWS Cognito user with Terraform

Tags: amazon-cognito, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to use Terraform to create AWS Cognito User Pool **with one test user**. Creating a user pool is quite straightforward:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "users" {
  name = "${var.cognito_user_pool_name}"
  admin_create_user_config {
    allow_admin_create_user_only = true
    unused_account_validity_days = 7
  }
}
```

However, I cannot find a resource that creates AWS Cognito user. It is doable with [AWS Cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-create-user.html)

```
aws cognito-idp admin-create-user --user-pool-id <value> --username <value>
```

Any idea on how to do it with Terraform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't currently possible directly in Terraform as there isn't a resource that creates users in a user pool.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4542) requesting the feature but no work has yet started on it.

Answer (score 7):

In order to automate things, it can be done in terraform using a [null_resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html) and `local_exec` provisioner to execute your `aws cli` command

e.g.

```py
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "pool" {
  name = "mypool"
}

resource "null_resource" "cognito_user" {

  triggers = {
    user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws cognito-idp admin-create-user --user-pool-id ${aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id} --username myuser"
  }
}
```

Comment: your solution is mentioned as a workaround : 
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4542

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that the `aws_cognito_user` resource is now supported in the AWS Terraform provider, as documented here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user

Version 4.3.0 at time of writing.

Answer (score 3):

As it is not possible to do that directly through Terraform in opposite to matusko solution I would recommend to use CloudFormation template.

In my opinion it is more elegant because:

- it does not require additional applications installed locally
- it can be managed by terraform as CF stack can be destroyed by terraform

Simple solution with template could look like below. Have in mind that I skipped not directly related files and resources like `provider`. Example also contains joining users with groups.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "COGITO_USERS_MAIL" {
  type = string
  description = "On this mail passwords for example users will be sent. It is only method I know for receiving password after automatic user creation."
}
```

**cf_template.json**

```
{
  "Resources" : {
    "userFoo": {
      "Type" : "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser",
      "Properties" : {
        "UserAttributes" : [
          { "Name": "email", "Value": "${users_mail}"}
        ],
        "Username" : "foo",
        "UserPoolId" : "${user_pool_id}"
      }
    },
    "groupFooAdmin": {
      "Type" : "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUserToGroupAttachment",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupName" : "${user_pool_group_admin}",
        "Username" : "foo",
        "UserPoolId" : "${user_pool_id}"
      },
      "DependsOn" : "userFoo"
    }
  }
}
```

**cognito.tf**

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user_pool" {
  name = "cogito-user-pool-name"
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "user_pool_domain" {
  domain       = "somedomain"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_group" "admin" {
  name         = "admin"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
}
```

**user_init.tf**

```
data "template_file" "application_bootstrap" {
  template = file("${path.module}/cf_template.json")

  vars = {
    user_pool_id          = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
    users_mail            = var.COGNITO_USERS_MAIL
    user_pool_group_admin = aws_cognito_user_group.admin.name
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "test_users" {
  name = "${var.TAG_PROJECT}-test-users"

  template_body = data.template_file.application_bootstrap.rendered
}
```

**Sources**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpooluser.html
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack

**Example**
Simple project based on:

- Terraform,
- Cognito,
- Elastic Load Balancer,
- Auto Scaling Group,
- Spring Boot application
- PostgreSQL DB.

Security check is made on ELB and Spring Boot.
This means that ELB can not pass not authorized users to application. And application can do further security check based on PostgreSQL roleswhich are mapped to Cognito roles.

Terraform Project and simple application:

- https://github.com/test-aws-cognito
  Docker image made out of application code:
- https://hub.docker.com/r/testawscognito/simple-web-app

More information how to run it in terraform git repository's README.MD.

Comment: What is var.COGNITO_USERS_MAIL here? A single user? A list of users?

Comment: I think I have named it wrongly and this is should be only one user mail. This is the mail on which password will be sent. I have done it quite some time ago but if I remember correctly terraform variable type `string` would not allow array. I'm planning to move from pure terraform to terragrunt so I will add this spelling to todo list.

Comment: OK. I have checked it. It is one mail for all users created with this terraform stack. Two users one mail ;)

Comment: If you are still interested - migration to terragrunt has been done. Now running the project should be much simpler.